# Determine whether element has fixed or percentage width using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

Using [Mootools Element.Dimensions](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions) I can get the computed size, in pixels, of any element. However, I can find no way of telling whether an element has been sized using pixel or percentage values (other than in the special case of its having an inline style).

Is there a sensible way of doing this? The only solution I can think of (which is so hideous that it barely deserves the name) is to walk through the document stylesheets, looking for selectors that match the target element and then looking through the declared styles for the target propety.

**Background**

I'm attempting to replace all textareas of a certain class with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) instances. Ideally, textareas with 100% width would be replaced by similarly styled editor instances - so they would scale on window resize -  while fixed size textareas would be replaced by fixed sized editors.

Yes, I could just give them a different class (which I will do if there's no nice solution), but ideally I'd like to be able to drop in my CKEditor script and have everything just work without having to tweak the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done. Looking at this question ([Why does getComputedStyle return 'auto' for pixels values right after element creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628005/why-does-getcomputedstyle-return-auto-for-pixels-values-right-after-element-cr)) gives us the hint.

If you set the element's style to display = none and then call getComputedStyle you will get the calculated value (percentage width or 'auto' or whatever the stylesheets apply to the element) instead of the pixel width.

Working code
jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wtxayrnm/1/

```
function getComputedCSSValue(ele, prop) {
  var resolvedVal = window.getComputedStyle(ele)[prop];
  //does this return a pixel based value?
  if (/px/.test(resolvedVal)) {
    var origDisplay = ele.style.display;
    ele.style.display = 'none';
    var computedVal = window.getComputedStyle(ele)[prop];
    //restore original display
    ele.style.display = origDisplay;
    return computedVal;
  } else {
    return resolvedVal;
  }
}
```

It should be noted that this will cause the layout to be re-rendered but, depending on your situation, it's probably a simpler solution than traversing all the stylesheet rules or cloning the element (which can cause some cascading rules to not be applied).

Comment: Awesome! Nearly 7 years after I first asked this question!

Comment: @werehamster the above method is only working for `percent` unit and not working for `'vw', 'rem', 'em'` units.

Answer (score 3):

Not that familiar with Motools but in jQuery you can do it.

Check here for a live demo http://jsbin.com/ewuqa

Or check this it handles also multiple matching CSS rules but only returns the correct value (the only thing I didn't bother to handle is if `!important` is set).

Included JS

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
http://github.com/hafriedlander/jquery.concrete/raw/master/vendor/jquery.selector/jquery.class.js
http://github.com/hafriedlander/jquery.concrete/raw/master/vendor/jquery.selector/jquery.selector.js
http://github.com/hafriedlander/jquery.concrete/raw/master/vendor/jquery.selector/jquery.selector.specifity.js
```

Own functions

```
function compare(as,bs) {
    return (as[0] - bs[0]) || (as[1] - bs[1]) || (as[2] - bs[2]);
}

//selector should only match a single element
//property is a css style-name
//returns the set css value (if set) for matched element, not the computed value
//also handles multiple matching rules and only returns most specific match
//doesn't handle !important
function whatIsSet(selector, property) {
    var se = $(selector);
    var regex = new RegExp("(.*)-(.)(.*)","g");
    var p = property;
    if (/-/.test(p)) {
        p = regex.exec(property);
        p = p[1] + p[2].toUpperCase() + p[3];
    }
    if (se.get(0).style[p] != undefined && se.get(0).style[p] != '')
        return se.get(0).style[p]; 

    var matchers = new Object();
    var mostSpecific = undefined;
    for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        //IE support
        var rules =
            document.styleSheets[i].cssRules ?
              document.styleSheets[i].cssRules :
              document.styleSheets[i].rules;
        for (var j=0; j < rules.length; j++)
            if (rules[j].style[p])
                if (jQuery.inArray(se, $(rules[j].selectorText)))
                    matchers[rules[j].selectorText] = rules[j].style[p];
    }
    for(var i in matchers) {
        if(mostSpecific != undefined) {
            var ms = $.selector(mostSpecific).specifity();
            var is = $.selector(i).specifity();
            mostSpecific = compare(ms, is) > 0  ? mostSpecific : i;
        } else
            mostSpecific = i;
    }
    return matchers[mostSpecific];
}
```

CSS

```
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }
#myElement {background-color: yellow; width:10%}
div {background-color: green; width:200px}
div#myElement  {background-color: blue; width:30%}
div.asd#myElement  {background-color: red; width:50%;}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="myElement" class="asd" style="width:91%">asd</div>
  <input
      type="button"
      onclick="javascript:alert('width originally set to: '+
          whatIsSet('#myElement', 'width'));"
      value="Tell me original width!"><br>
  <input
      type="button"
      onclick="javascript:alert('height originally set to: '+
          whatIsSet('#myElement', 'height'));"
      value="Tell me original height!"><br>
  <input
      type="button"
      onclick="javascript:alert('background-color originally set to: '+
          whatIsSet('#myElement', 'background-color'));"
      value="Tell me original background-color!"><br>
```

Comment: OK, that's impressive! I know I described this solution as hideous in my initial post; but, now I've actually seen it working, maybe it wouldn't be too bad. After all, if I'm already including 300kB of CKEditor, what's a few more. I'll have a go at implementing the same thing in Mootools.

Answer (score 1):

In IE, `element.currentStyle.width`. In many other browsers, `getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('width')`.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what Element.Dimensions uses. Unfortunately, this only gives the pixel values; it doesn't tell you whether the styles were originally specified in pixels or percentages.

Comment: @D. Evans: heh, implicit in your comment is that you don't-care/are-not-testing-in IE. `currentStyle` was made for your exact usecase. Unfortunately you're right, the other browsers compute the pixel dimensions.

Comment: Ah, you caught me out! You're right: I'm not particularly interested in IE-only solutions but it's worth knowing the option's there. For the first time in my life, I'm tempted to wish that other browser vendors would follow Microsoft's lead ;-)

Comment: I didn't think it always did this... on closer inspection, what Firefox is doing is returning the pixelised value when the `width` style is effective (such as on a block element), and the untouched CSS setting (potentially in other units, or `auto`) only when the width is ineffective (eg. on inline elements). Reading the CSS2 spec this is the difference between ‘computed values’ and ‘specified values’... if only there were a `getSpecifiedValue` call...

Comment: You want a solution without classnames to differentiate 100% from pixels? Wrap the textarea in a div with a fixed width and see if the textarea resizes. ;-) I didn't say it was a very nice solution...

Comment: @bobince: yeah, `getComputedStyle` has always worked like this. @D. Evans: if it's any condolence, jQuery doesn't let you at the inherited style either. In fact it goes out of its way to break it in IE (in the name of cross-browser consistency), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313995/how-can-i-get-the-font-size-of-an-element-as-it-was-set-by-css/1314845#1314845 Also check the accepted answer there. apparently it can be done in other browsers but I can't vouch for it.

Comment: @D. Evans: on 2nd read of that Q. the accepted answer is simply converting `px` to `em` s.

Answer (score 1):

I've migrated and updated my answer from a closed duplicate:

[How to tell if an element has a fluid width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880615/how-to-tell-if-an-element-has-a-fluid-width/12880776#12880776)

Not wanting to go down the route of scanning style declerations I found that this works... but unfortunately only for firefox :( To me it would make sense that if the element has nothing to compute it's width against (i.e. it's not part of the document flow) it should return it's original value - which is what FireFox does:

```
function isElementFluid(elm){
  var clone = elm.cloneNode(false);
  if( window.getComputedStyle ) {
    value = window.getComputedStyle(clone,null).width;
  } else if( clone.currentStyle ) {
    value = clone.currentStyle.width;
  }
  return (value && String(value).indexOf('%') != -1 );
}
```

*(have not tested for IE)*

Webkit and Opera however return a blank value - yet again another instance of where I agree with FireFox's implementation and frown at the others.

#### update 2

Ok, not a fan of being defeated by computers ;) so have come up with this function -- totally over the top, but it does seem to work. Again I have yet to test this on IE as I don't have a Windows machine to hand at the moment. It's annoying when the original FireFox-only version is quite succinct, but the logic here is sound - it falls back to what a normal human would do in testing if something is stretchy.

```
function isElementFluid(elm){
  var wrapper, clone = elm.cloneNode(false), ow, p1, p2;
  if( window.getComputedStyle ) {
    value = window.getComputedStyle(clone,null).width;
  } else if( clone.currentStyle ) {
    value = clone.currentStyle.width;
  }
  /// the browsers that fail to work as Firefox does
  /// return an empty width value, so here we fall back.
  if ( !value ) {
    /// remove styles that can get in the way
    clone.style.margin = '0';
    clone.style.padding = '0';
    clone.style.maxWidth = 'none';
    clone.style.minWidth = 'none';
    /// create a wrapper that we can control, my reason for
    /// using an unknown element is that it stands less chance
    /// of being affected by stylesheets - this could be improved
    /// to avoid possible erroneous results by overriding more css
    /// attributes with inline styles.
    wrapper = document.createElement('wrapper');
    wrapper.style.display = 'block';
    wrapper.style.width = '500px';
    wrapper.style.padding = '0';
    wrapper.style.margin = '0';
    wrapper.appendChild(clone);
    /// insert the element in the same location as our target
    elm.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper,elm);
    /// store the clone's calculated width
    ow = clone.offsetWidth;
    /// change the wrapper size once more
    wrapper.style.width = '600px';
    /// if the new width is the same as before, most likely a fixed width
    if( clone.offsetWidth == ow ){
      /// tidy up
      elm.parentNode.removeChild(wrapper);
      return false;
    }
    /// otherwise, calculate the percentages each time - if they
    /// match then it's likely this is a fluid element
    else {
      p1 = Math.floor(100/500*ow);
      p2 = Math.floor(100/600*clone.offsetWidth);
      /// tidy up
      elm.parentNode.removeChild(wrapper);
      return (p1 == p2) ? Math.round(p1)+'%' : false;
    }
  }
  else {
    p1 = (value && String(value).indexOf('%') != -1);
    return p1 ? value : false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can be done. You described the reason quite accurately: We have access to this kind of information only if it is in the element's style attribute. The only way I can think of is enlarge the parent container a bit and see if the textarea grows proportionately in size, but this is probably not always feasible, and probably hard to make cross-browser functional.

I'd be highly interested in more positive answers, though.