# Why does getComputedStyle return 'auto' for pixels values right after element creation?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I used Mustache to generate some HTML and used `insertAdjacentHTML` to place it on the page. It apparently converted to a DOM structure alright since I can get a handle to it afterwards by using a `document.querySelector('.contentarea')` call. However, if I try to get a pixel value for width or height, it keeps throwing back `'auto'`.

Thinking it might just be a problem with `getComputedStyle`, I tried using `.getBoundingClientRect` and `.offsetWidth` instead. Both returned `0`. It works if I delay the call slightly by placing it inside a `setTimeout(function(){}, 1)`, but that's not practical for my production code since it needs to go inside a synchronous constructor.

This is happening in both Firefox (Aurora), and Chrome.
I remembered reading an article on how Mozilla improved DOM manipulation performance by using lazy frame construction and thought there might be a bug with the frames being a little *too* lazy, but since it's happening in Chrome as well, that seems less likely.

Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on here or how to work around it? I really need the pixel height/width information immediately after inserting the HTML.

PS: Do any browsers do the HTML to DOM parsing/building in a separate thread? I was thinking that might cause this sort of behavior as well.

**NEVERMIND: It was my own fault. I just didn't notice a `display: none;` style that was set before the code tried to get the measurements.**

Comment: Can you post some relevant code? And is the HTML something that is visible and would cause a re-flow to occur? To force the browser to re-flow (and get the correct width or height) you should be able to use any of the following: offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight, scrollTop, scrollLeft, scrollWidth, scrollHeight, clientTop, clientLeft, clientWidth, clientHeight, or getComputedStyle() (currentStyle in IE).

Comment: You're right. I hunted through every preceding line of code and finally found that I had prematurely set `display: none;` on one of the parent elements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can cause a result of "auto". You found one of them; `display: none`. If an element is inline it will also return auto.

Essentially it must be a `block` or `inline-block` element and it must be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience many browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) purposefully delay computing layout until after Javascript threads end or yield via a timeout call.

Only solution I know is to yield to the browser and then restart. Your method of using `setTimeout` works well.

Comment: This is because the browse doesn't want to have to re-layout the page on every single DOM manipulation which could be really wasteful if you were doing a whole bunch of sequential manipulations.  So, it waits until your JS thread of execution finishes and then lays out the page and renders it.  Exactly how this works is browser-dependent.

Comment: I would have thought it would make an exception if the program specifically asks for the information by calling `getComputedStyle` or one of the others.

Comment: @download: yielding to the browser tells it to do its thing and (re)layout the dom changes/additions.