# jquery match elements with style font-size in px

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, inline-styles

How to target element with inline-style font-size defined in pixels (ex: font-size:12px) in order to modify font-size on a button click.

Can someone help finish this javascript code :

html

```
<div class='parent' style='font-size:15px'>
    <div>div 1 no inline styling</div>
    <div style='font-size:1em'>div 2 inlined font-size 1em</div>
    <div class='div-3'>div 3, CSS font-size:14px;</div>
    <div style='font-size:22px'>div 4 inlined font-size 22px</div>
    <div style='font-size:16pt'>div 5 inlined font-size 16pt</div>
    <div style='font-size:80%'>div 6 inlined font-size 80%</div>
</div>
<div id="output_box"></div>
```

javascript

```
$('*').filter(function() {
     /*var a-match-in-px-units = some-regular-expression-someelse-can-help-about;*/
     return $(this).css('font-size') == '11';
    $('#output_box').html($(this));
});

$("#trigger").click(function() {
    alert('to initialize font-size in px to bigger/lesser unit function()');    
   /* This is to apply font-resizing */     
});
```

I prepared [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqM3V/1/)

I found this other answer useful [Find elements which have greater font-size than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095684/find-elements-which-have-greater-font-size-than-specified#answer-6096494)

Comment: Downvote without a comment is not usefull.

Comment: +1 For this improvement.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery `.css('font-size')` always returns pixels, even if the original size was defined with a different unit. I would use `.attr('style')` instead (works with inline styles only) :

```
var result = $('*').filter(function () {
    var style = $(this).attr('style');
    return /font-size:[^;]+px/.test(style);
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/8LcD9/.

Comment: This looks like it. I'll give it a try 2morrow (it's passed 4h30am). wared, maybe you could help with this other question too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592165/increase-font-size-of-whole-web-page-on-button-click-event-using-jquery  I no need to take credit for your inspiration but this other question might be looking for your help too.

Comment: Poked again .. and yes i was tired.

Comment: @MilchePatern I've tried something there : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20618812/1636522. Currently, I need to know if OP has control over *non* inline styles in order to try a "lightweight" solution.

Comment: Greetings and happy new present moment wared. I was about to delete this question for avoiding duplication. Anyway, back to the point, your jsfiddle is not resulting in what i want and other answer is partial to suit my needs. I modified my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns I'm sorry, I guess I was tired too ^^'

Comment: After realizing the reformed question didn't suit the answer given, i rolled back and moved the improved question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937296/match-elements-with-inline-style-font-size-for-every-absolute-lengths-units

Answer (score 2):

You may try `indexOf` on style attribute:

```
$('.parent').each(function (index, value) {
    if (/font-size:[^;]+px/.test($(this).attr('style'))) {
        alert(index + ": " + $(this).attr('style'));
    }
});
```

[Here is Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqM3V/5/)

Comment: It's working. Here is playing demo http://jsfiddle.net/wqM3V/10/ Thanks to you and wared.

Comment: I am glad! it help u.. and best of luck :)

Comment: Season greetings, i modified my question for clarity and made it more representative of my real needs. Perhaps you could take a second look.

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns will recommend u to ask another question instead of editing this one.

Comment: I followed your advice and here is the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937296/match-elements-with-inline-style-font-size-for-every-absolute-lengths-units