# match elements with inline-style font-size for every absolute lengths units

Tags: javascript, regex, user-interface, jquery-selectors

I need help for a jQuery fonction.

Per say, i want to change the font-size of the whole document, first task is to increment the font size of the `<body>` tag in order to make all relative units, like em or rem, modified. But what about inlined font-size and old-timer `<font size="x">`? Also, i want to apply the modification to `line-height` so everything re-format nicely.

Can someone help finish this code with a filter that will match :

- `<font size="2">`
- `<div style"font-size:14px;line-height:17px">`
- `<div style"font-size:14‘cm’, ‘mm’, ‘in’, ‘pt’, ‘pc’ and ‘px’;line-height:xyz">`

html

```
<div class='parent' style='font-size:15px'>
    <div>div 1 no inline styling</div>
    <div style='font-size:1em'>div 2 inlined font-size 1em</div>
    <div class='div-3'>div 3, CSS font-size:14px;</div>
    <div style='font-size:22px'>div 4 inlined font-size 22px</div>
    <div style='font-size:16pt'>div 5 inlined font-size 16pt</div>
    <div style='font-size:80%'>div 6 inlined font-size 80%</div>
    <div><font size="2">legacy html font size="2"</font></div>
</div>
<div id="output_box"></div>
```

*After a few trys and helping answers from [@wared and @ZaheerAhmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592932/jquery-match-elements-with-style-font-size-in-px)* , i could reform this javascript. I don't know how to test for every lenght units targeted otherwise than a multiple `if-then-else` algorythm and the use of universal selector `'*'` might not be a good idea, any suggestions?.

javascript :

```
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    /* the overall body tag for relative units */
    $("body").css("font-size","+=5%");
    /* targetting inlined font-size in pixels */     
    $('*').each(function (index, value) {
        if (/font-size:[^;]+px/.test($(this).attr('style'))) {
            $(this).css("font-size","+=2");
        }
    });
});
```

I prepared [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqM3V/11/)

---

*[msdn values and units reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537660.aspx)*

Relative length units

- em    The computed font-size. ex  The height of a lowercase "x".
- px    Pixels, relative to the viewing device.
- % Percentage.
- rem   The font size of the root element.
- *those are not to consider with actual question*
- vw    The viewport width.
- vh    The viewport height.
- vm    The smaller value of viewport width or height.
- ch    Zero-width (width of the zero glyph in the rendering font).

Absolute length units

- in    Inches (1 inch = 2.54 centimeters).
- cm    Centimeters.
- mm    Millimeters.
- pt    Points (1 point = 1/72 inches).
- pc    Picas (1 pica = 12 points).

---

[A usefull article from Klemen Slavič](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj687762.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> First task is to increment the font size of the  tag in order to
>   make all relative units, like em or rem, modified

Yes, you are right.

> But what about inlined font-size and old-timer `<font size="x">`?

Remove all of them and use a stylesheet. You should separate presentation from content.

Comment: Hi Oriol and thanks for your answer. I know about front-end design and best practices. I am trying to build a script to resize font-size for older websites.

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns But I don't think a JS script is the solution. It won't work in browsers with JS disabled, it will slow down the load of the page, ... Maybe you could try a server-side script to remove inline styles from the code

Comment: I understand your point about rewriting html server-side, but this is not my goal and this would imply that the backend/content is under my control of some sort. I just need to implement a [+] and [-] font sizing button witch can treat every possible way styling has been done.