# How can I get the actual inherited CSS of an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Using JavaScript, how can I get the *actual* value for a CSS property which is *inherited*?

For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<p><span style="font-size:24pt;">Test #1</span></p>​
<p style="font-size:24pt;">Test <span style="font-weight:bold;">#2</span></p>​
```

Using the jQuery code `$('p span').css('fontSize')` will yield `32px` not `24pt`  because it uses `getComputedStyle` which returns the *used value*, not the *actual inherited value*. But sometimes the style will be directly on the element I am targeting, sometimes it will be inherited.

[Here is a test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mvqPE/). How can I get the *actual* inherited CSS of an element using JavaScript?

Comment: The issue here is that the value is being converted to pixels.  `32px` is `24pt`.  http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html  Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mvqPE/1/

Comment: @Rocket: Right. That's *exactly* the issue I am trying to solve :-p and that's what I mean by `actual` vs `used` value

Comment: Pretty sure you can't get the "actual" value (short of reading the `style` attribute).  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1314845

Comment: It's looking that way...

Comment: Maybe you can get the px value and convert it to pt...

Comment: Yeah, someone mentioned I could precompute the `px` values of all the `pt` sizes I have, then use a lookup table to convert.

Comment: `(32px * 72) / 96 = 24pt` :-P

Comment: That's an oversimplified formula. `25pt -> 33px` but `33*72/96==24.75pt`. Also this depends on font face, OS, browser, zoom, and a wide variety of other things.

Comment: Because you are making a web interface (pixels). You should be using pixels and or ems for measurements anyway. Also, never use inline styles, its makes the styles unmanageable for future developers.

Comment: You have no idea what I am doing @laymanje. In fact you're completely wrong. I am developing a *print layout system* and the inline styles are placed there by my CMS.

Comment: (Unrelated, poor man's private messaging, will delete this soonish: [your PNG clock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it/79289#79289) seems to be broken?)

Comment: ([That clock](http://josh.gitlin.name/time3.php), by the way, is used in that post from Pekka; see [its source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/a7d937c5-b98a-42d1-9b40-944e18a57cc7/view-source).)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @mikerobi would satisfy your test case, but to be more specific the only CSS properties exposed by the browsers are from `getComputedStyle`, so if it's wrong there that's about as good as it gets. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5000507/237211) from another question for more detail.

Comment: (Seems the reference to mikerobi is is a bit outdated?)